# ASP.NET SCORM Authoring Tool Free

Tags: c#, asp.net, scorm

Is there any module or library available that I can use in my project to make my LMS SCORM compliant?

Right now my need is to make my courses SCORM compliant.

Answer (score 2):

When making something SCORM conformant, the first thing you need to do is distinguish whether you are creating courses or an LMS. You mention both in your post.

A good way to frame the question is:

If you want to be able to import other people’s content into your system, you are making your LMS SCORM conformant. (In which case, [SCORM Engine](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/) is a library you can add to an existing LMS to make it SCORM conformant.)

If you want to be able to play your content in someone else’s system, you are making SCORM conformant content. (For content, [SCORM Driver](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-driver/) is wrapper you can put around existing content to make it SCORM conformant).